# How to view source code of dependencies in Visual Studio 2015 by clicking F12?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Clicking F12 on functions from some of dependencies always results with some, often useless, list of variables and methods of class:

[image: What I see after clicking F12 on class from one of dependencies]

It of course provides some brief explanation/summary of what code does, but I often need some more details, preferably: see the code.

Since ASP.net [is open-source now](https://github.com/aspnet), I wonder if there was some possibility to view actual source code of class (using F12 button) instead of showing this metadata. Is there some plugin for that?

Comment: Don't know why anyone would downvote this, seems like a perfectly legitimate question. Have an upvote.

Comment: One way to view is to decompile the library you want to explore. See [https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/features/](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/features/)

Answer (score 0):

I've found some interesting Visual Studio extension. It basically do what I wanted.

[Ref12](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f89b27c5-7d7b-4059-adde-7ccc709fa86e)

It unfortunately doesn't support every .NET classess (especially those from the new asp.net core seems to be missing), but it will definitely be useful either way.